# How to show that $\infty$ is isolated?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

A point $p$ in a topological space $Y$ is *isolated* if there exists an open set $O$ such that $p \in O$, but $(Y \setminus \{p\}) \cap O=\emptyset$

Suppose that $X$ is compact. Show that $\infty$ is isolated in the one-point extension of $X_\infty$ of $X$. Is $X$ dense in $X_\infty$? Prove that $X_\infty$ is disconnected.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close with reading the comments.

Comment: A simpler way to state the definition is that $p$ is isolated if $\{p\}$ is open. Anyway, the answer to your question is clear from the _definition_ of  $X_\infty$ (and its topology). What is that definition?

Answer (score 1):

By definition of the Alexandroff extension, every subset $(X \setminus C) \cup \lbrace \infty \rbrace$, where $C$ is compact in $X$, is an open set of $X_{\infty}$. So here, with $C = X$, you get that $\lbrace \infty \rbrace$ is open, so $\infty$ is isolated in $X_{\infty}$.

$X$ is not dense in $X_{\infty}$ because the open set $\lbrace \infty \rbrace$ does not intersect $X$.

$X_{\infty}$ is disconnected because it is the disjoint union of the two closed sets $X$ and $\lbrace \infty \rbrace$.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the topology on $X_\infty$ tells us that all sets of the form $(X\setminus C) \cup \{\infty\}$ are open in $X_\infty$, where $C$ is compact and closed in $X$, (plus all open subsets of $X$ as well).

If $X$ is compact, we can choose it as $C$ in the previous paragraph, and we get that $\emptyset \cup \{\infty\} = \{\infty\}$ is open in $X_\infty$. This $O=\{\infty\}$ we can take as the $O$ in your definition of isolated point.

$X$ is not dense in $X_\infty$ because $\{\infty\}$ is a non-empty open set of $X_\infty$ that does not intersect $X$ (or we can say too that $\infty \notin \overline{X}$ if you prefer).

As $X$ is open in $X_\infty$ too and also closed (as its complement $\{\infty\}$ is open), the sets $X$ and $\{\infty\}$ form a decomposition of $X_\infty$ and so the latter space is disconnected.